# How to access azure sql database from webjob?

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs

How I am trying to execute the program which uses azure database. The program works fine in local environment but not when I run it as webjob. This is the error in webjob console:

```
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]  System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 197.
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<SetConnectionString>b__18(DbConnection t, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 c)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at Data.Repository.Repository`1.FirstOrDefault(Expression`1 predicate) in D:\Projects\Repository\Repository.cs:line 594
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at ConfigurationService.GetConfigValueByConfigCode(String configType, String configCode, IUnitOfWork uow) in D:\Projects\Configurations\ConfigurationService.cs:line 159
[06/28/2022 07:59:46 > fa1ef8: INFO]    at ArchiveOldSMBFiles.Program.ProcessMethod() in D:\Projects\ArchiveOldSMBFiles\Program.cs:line 104
```

The stack trace shows error in my  line number 159 of ConfigurationService.cs, well this is when i am calling database. This is the code at line number 159:

```
var configuration = repository.FirstOrDefault(filterPredicate);
```

This is my code:

```
class Program
    {
        private static IServiceCollection services;
        private static IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
        private static ILogger<Program> logger;
        private static TelemetryClient telemetryClient;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder
                    .AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("",
                        LogLevel.Trace))
                .AddSingleton(typeof(ITelemetryChannel), new InMemoryChannel())
                .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationInsightKey"]);

            serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            telemetryClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>();

            using (telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("Archive"))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var unitOfWork = new DataConnector().UnitOfWork)
                    {
                        var jsonTemplate = ConfigurationService.GetConfigValueByConfigCode(unitOfWork);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.log(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    telemetryClient.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

and this is my application config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="IsHostedInWebJob" value="true" />
        <add key="APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" value="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" />
        <!--<add key="ApplicationInsightKey" value="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" />-->
        <add key="LocalPath" value="E:\JsonLog" />
        <add key="StorageConnectionString2" value="azure-storage-fileshare" />
        <add key="StorageConnectionString1" value="azure-storage-fileshare" />
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Entities" connectionString="data source=[Server Name];initial catalog=[Database Name];user id=[Login id];password=[Password];multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Azure.Core" publicKeyToken="92742159e12e44c8" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.23.0.0" newVersion="1.23.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Identity.Client" publicKeyToken="0a613f4dd989e8ae" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.30.1.0" newVersion="4.30.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encodings.Web" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.4.0" newVersion="4.0.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.40.0.0" newVersion="1.40.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Auth" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.40.0.0" newVersion="1.40.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib" publicKeyToken="1b03e6acf1164f73" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.2.10" newVersion="1.3.2.10" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.20.0.103" newVersion="2.20.0.103" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.1.0" newVersion="2.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.1.0" newVersion="2.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.1.0" newVersion="2.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.1.0" newVersion="2.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.1.0" newVersion="2.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.20.0.103" newVersion="2.20.0.103" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.20.0.103" newVersion="2.20.0.103" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.20.0.103" newVersion="2.20.0.103" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.20.0.103" newVersion="2.20.0.103" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.20.0.103" newVersion="2.20.0.103" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.1.0" newVersion="2.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory.Data" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.1.0" newVersion="1.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.6.2.0" newVersion="4.6.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone help me and let me know where I am going wrong?

I am uploading webjob by zipping **Debug** Folder after deleting `WinSCP.exe` file inside debug folder because it is crashing whole webjob.

Answer (score 0):

> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 197.

This error we get because of incorrect form of connection string to Azure SQL database.

You can get connection string for Azure database from here:
[image]